# Perl: Finding out if a given number is a prime number

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a subroutine that determines whether or not the number passed in is prime, and it's not working correctly. The numbers I'm passing in should not be identified as prime. Is there a logic error, or something about Perl that I'm missing?

```
sub isPrime {

    my ( $n ) = @_;

    for ( my $i = 3 ; $i < $n ; $i++ ) {

        if ( $n % $i == 0 ) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know even numbers are not prime?

Comment: You only need to test up to sqrt($n).  For large n, there are more efficient ways (google prime number seive).

Comment: also, you should remove the else block and put return 1 after the for loop.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. It looks like you applied the answer to your question, which makes the question make much less sense.

Comment: Please don't keep fixing your question. I also have had to roll back your edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your function is checking just if n is not divisible by 3 because it calls `return` immediately after the fisrt test.

Try to make the function `return 0` within the `for` loop, and `return 1` outside it, or set a flag for the number being prime that is initially true and return its value after the loop.

You should also start your `for` loop at 2, not at 3, otherwise you aren't testing for even numbers.

Comment: I made some changes as you suggested, this seems to work better, but still doesn't do  primes correctly.

Comment: Haha, don't worry, we all make them :D

Comment: @Octi: Stack Overflow is not a forum. You shouldn't be following the edits of the original question and adjusting your answer accordingly. It might have been better to fix and test the code and show a working version than to describe the required edits in English

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code I wrote in about 40 minutes. Don't hate if it is inefficient, I am still learning perl.

```
print ("This is a prime number checker!\n");
print ("Enter a number below to check it:\n");
$y = 0;
$num = <>;
for ($i = $num; $i > 0; $i--) {
    if ($num % $i == 0) {
        $y += 1;
    }
}
if ($y > 2) {
    print ("$num is not a prime!");
} else {
    print ("$num is a prime!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my code. It uses logic in the sense that it checks if the current number can be divisible by any number that came before it, excluding any even numbers.

```
sub is_prime {
    my ($num) = @_;

    return 0 if $num <= 2;
    return 0 if $num % 2 == 0 ;

    for (my $i = 3; $i < $num; $i += 2) {
       if($num % $i == 0){
            return 0;
       }
    }

    return 1;
}
```